# How can my web browser application get the open url from another application

Tags: winforms, webbrowser-control

I have created a "Windows Forms Application" project by Visual Studio.Net 2008.

In order to set my appliction as the default web browser for my operating system, I modify registry as below:

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\HTTP\shell\open\command]
@="\"F:\My Browser\bin\Debug\My Browser.exe\" -nohome"

and then i click a link in a "Live Messenger" window to test.

http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_lktgSLsaLgU/R3di1ZNDyWI/AAAAAAAACWQ/u1xcH9W0g_I/s400/vicito-news.png

As a result, it will open my application. the problem is that, I can't find out the URL I clicked in the "args" argument of the "Main" method belong to the "Program" class.

```
public static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
}
```

Where I can find out the URL? Or how can I find out the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your registry key should include the %1 directive that instructs the shell to pass the URL parameter into the browsers arguments.

So in your case the correct registry is:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\HTTP\shell\open\command] @="\"F:\My Browser\bin\Debug\My Browser.exe\" "%1"
```

Comment: Thank you every much! I have tested according to your answer and take affect.